# Show grails test results in Netbeans IDE

Tags: unit-testing, grails, netbeans, junit

does anybody know a possibility to show the Unit-Test results of a grails project in the "Test Result"-Window of the netbeans IDE? The test results are saved in the project folder as JUnit XML Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like there is any such integration like there is for e.g. Ruby.

For Java projects, the IDE does not wait for XML files to be written to a build directory; it listens for special events in the Ant `<junit>` task and reports them immediately.

I do not think much work is being done on the Groovy support generally, but perhaps someone could write a plugin which just waits for `TEST-*.xml` to appear in some build directory, and displays them in Test Results. This would require using the org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner API (currently not published for public use). Such a plugin could be handy not just for Grails users.

Comment: nice idea. Dont know if i'm able to do this, but maybe it worth a try

Answer (score 0):

It is in the target/test-reports/html/index.html from project window.  Just right click on it and choose view.

Comment: I know that :-) But I'm looking for the direct integration like the one for Java-Projects where you can browse the results in the Testresult window.

Comment: Seems that there is no other solution for the current version of netbeans